# generating js objects names and adding values to them

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops, for-loop

I generate two random arrays and I need to add numbers from them to array which I need to fill with 100 Objects, name them from `n1 to n100` and make them look like this:

```
n1...n100 = {r: realArray[0...100], i: imagArray[0...100])}
```

Of course I can add them like I did when there were few of them:

```
var realArray = [],
    imagArray = [];

for (var i=0, t=100; i<t; i++) {
    realArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * t) - 50);
    imagArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * t) - 50);
}

  var pointsValues = [
  n1 = {r: realArray[0], i: imagArray[0]},
  n2 = {r: realArray[1], i: imagArray[1]},
  n3 = {r: realArray[2], i: imagArray[2]},
  n4 = {r: realArray[3], i: imagArray[3]},
  n5 = {r: realArray[4], i: imagArray[4]},
  n6 = {r: realArray[5], i: imagArray[5]},
  n7 = {r: realArray[6], i: imagArray[6]},
  n8 = {r: realArray[7], i: imagArray[7]},
  n9 = {r: realArray[8], i: imagArray[8]},
  n10 = {r: realArray[9], i: imagArray[9]},
  n11 = {r: realArray[10], i: imagArray[10]},
  n12 = {r: realArray[11], i: imagArray[11]},
  //........................................,
  //........................................,
  //........................................,
  n100 = {r: realArray[100], i: imagArray[100]},
    ];
```

I know there must be way to do this with a loop, but I can't figure out how to do it, the idea of changing names from `n1 to n100` confuses me the most.

Comment: what means `n1`? is it a kind of index? or should it be an key for an object?

Comment: @NinaScholz it's a key for an object

Comment: what exactly? an array or an object? are `realArray` and `imagArray` necessary for other use, than jut to generate `pointsValues`?

Comment: @NinaScholz object. It's necessary to increment index of both `realArray[n]` and `imagArray[n]` while adding a key to an object from `n1 to n100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing with `var pointsValues = [ ... n1 = {r: realArray[0], i: imagArray[0]},` is creating a global variable named `n1` (at least, if you're not in strict mode). What I think you need is a simple object since array indices can only be numbers while object keys are usually strings. You can access indices of objects using the known bracket notation (`foo['n1']`). So, a possible solution would be the following:

```js
var realArray = [],
    imagArray = [];

for (var i=0, t=100; i<t; i++) {
    realArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * t) - 50);
    imagArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * t) - 50);
}

var result = {};

var len = realArray.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  result['n' + (i + 1)] = {
    r: realArray[i],
    i: imagArray[i],
  };
}

console.log(result);
console.log(result['n50']);
```

Of course, there are other solutions which may be better suited, but that's dependent on the exact use case.

Comment: Why two `for` loops when you could do it with one?

Comment: @JordanRunning The first one was taken from the initial code of the OP. That's what I meant with "there may be better suited solutions". We do not have information about what he's gonna do with the arrays besides creating the object. If it was just that, we would not need to create the arrays, either.

Answer (score 0):

you can use *pointValues* as a object, so you can do the inserts on a for loop, like this:

```
var pointsValues = {}

for(var j = 0; j<100; j++){
    var index = "n"+(j+1);
    pointsValues[index] = {r: realArray[j], i: imagArray[j]};
}
```

so you can access the values using *pointsValues.n1* or *pointsValues['n1']*, and iterate over with with a foreach!

Comment: Yes. But please, declare `j` before usage via the `var` keyword (or `let` respectively `const` in newer JavaScript).

Comment: @SVSchmidt Oh, sorry, don't see it! Thanks